# How does Berserker Rage interact with Boulder Toss?

Tags: diablo-iii

Berserker Rage gives 25% damage when fury is near full, and Boulder Toss uses your entire fury bar for huge amounts of damage. How does these two skills interact?

Do you get the large increase in damage from throwing the boulder near max fury work? Or does it set your fury to zero and then do the damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the Boulder Toss benefit from the Berserker Rage 25% damage bonus (You can get a confirmation  [by this MVP](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/10887508679#4) or [this topic](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9939563977) on the forum).